# Integrate Google Analytics and Mysql Workbench

Tags: google-analytics, mysql-workbench

How can i integrate google analytics database and mysql workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics does not use MySql (or any other relational database - that just wouldn't scale) so you can't use tools that are designed for MySql.

You could, in a very roundabout way, use Google App Script to pull data  from GA, insert it in your own MySql database (provided the database is remotely accessible) and hook up the MySql workbench to your database after you've populated it with data from you GA account.

However there would be very little point in doing so - you would have to come up with your own database structure (mapping your GA data to some relational database structure) and it would in no way be fit to replicate the functionality of GA. Any kind of reporting you could do with this kind of setup you could do much more easily  with the tools already provided by Google.

Comment: I dont know....seems like if someone only wanted the most important KPIs out of GA it would make a whole lot of since to store it in your your own db for integrating with other data and calculating metrics that G doesn't provide.... Just sayin..